# How can i add this random integer numbers?

Tags: java

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class RandomIntegers {

    public static void main( String args[] ) {
        int value;
        String output = "";
        // loop 20 times
        for ( int counter = 1; counter <= 20; counter++ ) {
            // pick random integer between 1 and 6    
            value = 1 + ( int ) ( Math.random() * 6 );
            output += value + "  ";  // append value to output
            // if counter divisible by 5, append newline to String output
            if ( counter % 5 == 0 )
                output += "\n";
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, output, "20 Random Numbers from 1 to 6",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE );
        System.exit( 0 );
    }
}
```

what i want to do is to get the sum .for example :
5 4 3 2 1 = 15 just like this.

Comment: How to add numbers? num1 + num2.

Answer (score 1):

Simply initialize a variable `sum` to 0, then add `value` to it:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class RandomIntegers {

    public static void main( String args[] ) {
        int value;
        String output = "";
        int sum = 0; 
        // loop 20 times
        for ( int counter = 1; counter <= 20; counter++ ) {
            // pick random integer between 1 and 6
            value = 1 + ( int ) ( Math.random() * 6 );
            sum += value;            // Simply add value to sum
            output += value + "  ";  // append value to output
            // if counter divisible by 5, append newline to String output
            if ( counter % 5 == 0 )
                output += "\n";
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, output, "20 Random Numbers from 1 to 6",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE );
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, sum, "Total:",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE );
        System.exit( 0 );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Really not clear on what you are trying to do, or what your question is here. If I can guess, it's about this line of code:

```
value = 1 + ( int ) ( Math.random() * 6 );
```

Are you just trying to get a random integer here? You can do that a different way:

```
Random rand;
int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
```

You can see a more detailed explanation here: [How do I generate random integers within a specific range in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/generating-random-integers-in-a-range-with-java)